# How to convert cdata from xml to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, cdata

I'm receiving XML data via AJAX and the XML includes some CDATA values.

Example:

```
<xml>
      <mytag>
            <![CDATA[
                <img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/14.gif"/><br />
                <b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
            ]]>
      </mytag>
</xml>
```

and I like to have for the ... at the div-tag with class="title" the content from the b-tag and at the div-tag class="current-img" an img-tag with the right src

```
<html>
      <body>
            <div class="weather">
                <div class="title">...</div>
                <div class="current-img">...</div>
            </div
      </body>
</html>
```

for now I created a jQuery Object from the data and tried to get with .text() the data but how can I get a special data just the `<img src="..."/>`

```
var $weather = $(".weather");
$.ajax({
   url: "yahooweather.php?w=782458",
   context: document.body,
   success: function(data){
        $xml = $(data).find("xml mytag");

            $weather.find(".title").html($xml.children("b")); //this isnt working!


   var str = $xml.text()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-convert-xml-with-cdata-to-html-and-back-again#14737000002282604

> I had the same problem, and solved it just by sending the right header (text/xml) with the xml answer. 
>   Now .text() returns the right html content between the CDATA tags.

It looks like it depends on correct content type.

Comment: what does this mean? sending the right header (text/xml) with the xml answer - which header?

Comment: Each request sends and receives header and body of data. Header is the descriptive part of the data (which also describes data's format). 'Content-Type' in header describes the format (mime-type) and force the browser to read data correctly. For example, if XML structure received with 'Content-Type: text/html', browser will think it is HTML, not XML. Etc.